# Simulating sea level rise using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sea-level-rise

I am trying to look at how sea level rise would cover a certain area using a DEM.

Is there a way to do this sort of simulation using ArcGIS desktop?

I am trying to look at how much area would be covered with 1ft of sea level rise, 2ft, etc, so set heights.

Comment: Get a DEM and create a contour at 1ft, 2ft etc and you'll be fairly close *but* take into account the highest astronomical tide as your starting value; this sort of modelling is only to be used for a moderate size area (city sized) as the HAT value changes significantly over larger areas. Tsunami modelling and flood modelling is much more complex but the sea, being mostly static, doesn't need allowances for water flow over time.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33353/8104